# Spring Data Rest does not fetch nested objects from Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

Following "_links" from an Object the return Json object is empty. I suppose this is because of the lack of automatic lazy fetching in SDN.

**Is there an easy way to tell SDR to fetch objects before returning them?**

Example:

`.../questions/1131` returns the following JSON:

```
{
  //...
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/questions/1131"
    },
    "askedBy" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/questions/1131/askedBy"
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

Clicking on `.../questions/1131/askedBy` should return a User, but it returns a User object, where all the properties are `null`, except the links, which are correct.

How can I tell SDR to fetch these embedded objects before converting them to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a bit hackish, but I have found a working solution.

```
@Bean
@Transactional
public ResourceProcessor<Resource> fetchProcessor() {
    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource>() {
        @Autowired
        Neo4jTemplate template;

        @Override
        public Resource process(Resource resource) {
            final Object content = resource.getContent();
            if (content != null) {
                template.fetch(content);
            }
            return resource;
        }
    };
}
```

Also, I think it is a bit overkill, as it calls `template.fetch()` even if the object is already populated.

A better idea, anyone?